# 403 Forbidden when http request body has > 5000 Guids (Happens only on Mobile device browsers)

Tags: axios, httprequest, http-status-code-403

I have a weird problem with my react app when exporting a list of records as csv. Here's the simple flow I have setup:

- User selects a group of item from UI
- Export modal opens
- Submit will send an API call with all GUIDs that the user selected and the API generates excels and returns the data. Pretty straight forward.
- The max number of items they can export can go up-to 14000 right now.

On Desktop & DevTools Device simulator:

- This feature works without issues on desktop no matter how many GUIDs we send in the http request body.

On Mobile devices (Both iOS and Android):

- User do not see any issues up until the GUIDs reach a count of 5000.
  Here's an example of the post call with 1417 GUIDs:

  [image: Request with < 5000]
- Here's how it looks after I cross 5000:

  [image: Request with 5104 GUIDs]

  In this case, the API call is not reaching the APIM at all.

Screenshots are from Browserstack.

Our API is hosted on Azure behind APIM. I have all the cors policies setup. I don't see any kind of request limitation too. Even if there was, I would expect a 'Request Size exceeds' error. But 403 doesn't make any sense to me in this scenario. I have tested this on my mobile as well and see the same behavior.

We also have another feature in our webapp that sends out more than 5000 GUIDs and the problem was there as well.

Here are the things I've tried with no outcome:

- We use axios for http request in react app. Tried to increase the request body size limit for axios instance.
- Check request limits on APIM
- Different iOS and Android devices and browser. Behavior is still same.

I couldn't find an article anywhere on the internet that explains why this would happen.

I've been trying this for over two weeks now. And I expect the API call to go through and return 200 response back.

Any help from anyone would be really appreciated.

**Update:**

This is how I've setup cors policy in APIM. Sorry I have to hide all urls since they're confidential.
[CORS Policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyIak.png)

Comment: How do you pass guids over the network? is it a part of a path/query params or body? If you use APIM with subscription keys the mobile browser could trim the url up to 5000 guids (that would be weird I admit) and some mandatory parameters attached to the end of the URL could be cut off, thus 403 response. For now I can't think of anything else.

Comment: You say "I have all the cors policies setup", but your error code says the origin is not allowed. There must be some difference in headers sent by mobile browsers, or if there isn't maybe something along that network path is changing them.

Comment: @IgorLevicki Yes I have allowed origin in cors policy. That’s why it works fine if I send less than 5000. I don’t see differences in request headers when it fails

Comment: @Jacek I’m sending guide in body . you can see it in the screenshots)

Comment: The error message in your screenshot literally says "Origin https://____com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin". How are you setting it, and does the server code actually check if the Origin which mobile client sends is allowed? Does the client request via GET or POST? You need to provide a bit more details.

Comment: I've made an update to the description here with a screenshot of APIM config that shows the cors policy. I have my app url in the list of origins.
The request type is POST you can refer to the first screenshot that is returning 200.
I understand it looks like a CORS error but if it was really cors, it should block all requests coming from webapp. It doesn't make sense that it only blocks when GUIds are > 5000 in count. Hope this gives you a bit more context.